# Retornar erro do controller para o JS (Jquery/Ajax)

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax, json

Como verificar erro no retorno de uma chamada `Jquery` por ajax para uma `controller`. Este retorno não veio formatado como gostaria, apenas verificando os campos customizados.

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         url: "MyController/Create",
         data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
         success: function (result) {
           if(result.error>0)
         {            
             alert("Error:" + result.ErrorMessage ); 
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Um Jeito para enviar o erro para o JS é atualizar o Status Code do objeto `response` e customizar uma msg de erro para o retorno.

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Create(MyObject myObject) 
{
  //Tudo certo
  return Json(new { IsCreated = True, Content = ViewGenerator(myObject));

  //A inclusão não aconteceu mas não causou erro ao processo
  return Json(new { IsCreated = False, Content = ViewGenerator(myObject));  

  //Erro
  Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
  return Json(new { IsCreated = false, ErrorMessage = 'Minha MSG de erro');
}
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "MyController/Create",
     data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
     success: function (result) {
       if(result.IsCreated)
     {
    //... Tudo certo
     }
     else
     {
    //... A inclusão não aconteceu mas não causou erro ao processo
     }
   },
    error: function (error) {
            alert("Erro:" + erro.responseJSON.ErrorMessage ); //Erro
        }
  });
```